# move 3d cursor after enabling emulate 3 mouse button

Tags: 3d-cursor

I use right click to select so i was using alt cursor access option but after enabling emulate 3 mouse button i can't seem to access that
emulate 3 mouse button is disabling the alt cursor access so is there any way to move the cursor without selecting the cursor from tool bar?
blender version 4.0